# how to I clean some time range in R and make them more meaningful?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am still very new at R. When I try to clean some reports I get a column called"funding period" where there are so  many different formats of time ranges for different projects, such as

```
project 1, 01/01/2018 - 12/31/2020
project 2, Annual
project 3, Every 2 Years
project 4, CY 2018
project 5, FY 18-20
project 6, FY 2018
```

I intend to split these ranges and instead assign a start date and end date to each project, like this:

`project, start_date, end_date 
project 1, 01-01-2018, 12-31-2020
project 2, 01-01-2018，12-31-2018
project 3, 01-01-2017, 12-31-2018
project 4, 01-01-2018，12-31-2018
project 5, 01-01-2018, 12-31-2020
project 5, 01-01-2018, 12-31-2018`

but I do not know exactly how. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `lubridate` package can handle a lot of different formats, though I don't know if it will handle all of these. There's a difference in my mind, though, between handling a *date range* (lines 1 and 4-6) and a *date period* (2-3). Please extend your question (edit) by adding what you think each of these should translate into.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! Sorry I am still not very familiar with the website's system, I will update the question as soon as possible

Comment: YiZhang, I think you need to provide expected output for all of your ranges/periods, since it is not clear when `Every 2 Years` should stop and start.

Comment: got it! Ill change it now

Comment: How do you know that project 3 starts on jan 1, 2018? Why not Aug 14, 1992? Also, "CY" vs "FY" do not follow national, corporate, or other calendars of which I'm aware (and I'm not assuming US ... are there regions where CY=FY?). I think proj 5 has a typo, should it be 2020? If there are other columns (omitted here) that are relevant for determining which years or dates are relevant, please include more.

Comment: Hi Evans, Thanks for posting. To be honest, I actually do not know because I haven't got the chance to talk to the persons who wrote these reports... there are many, many of them, but the data I got is named 2018 work plan, so I just assume they are talking about the recent years and their FY is the same as CY. Basically, I want to learn a method to deal with the issue in general and then went back and adjust it to my specific questions...and I corrected the typo! Thanks for reminding.

Comment: That's some of the logic I was leading towards ... when you say "recent years" and this-year (2018) data, suggesting there's another field with date or a full timestamp. It sounds like you need to clarify some of your data back-story. Good luck.